# Kafka consumer in spark failing with the error java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, abstract

I am trying to query kafka from earliest offset to latest offset and then writing it to hadoop.

However the problem is that I am getting `java.lang.AbstractMethodError` even though I am not calling any abstract method in my code.

This is the code through which I am trying to query kafka

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SaveMode, SparkSession}
import org.json.JSONObject

case class Metric(timestamp: String, hostName: String)


object KafkaMetrcs {

  val logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass.getName)

  def getSparkConf(appName: String): SparkConf = {
    new SparkConf().setAppName(appName)
    //.setMaster("local[*]")

  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {


    val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
    implicit val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).getOrCreate()
    sparkSession.sparkContext.setLogLevel("INFO")

    import sparkSession.implicits._


    val bootstrapServers = "kafka-vip.com:1234"
    val outputLocation = "hdfs://kafka_metrics/output"

    val inputds = sparkSession.read.format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootstrapServers)
      .option("subscribe", "fpti.platform.metrics")
      .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
      .option("endingOffsets", "latest")
      .option("fetchOffset.numRetries", 5)
      .option("failOnDataLoss", "false")
      .load()
      .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
      .as[String]


    val outputds = inputds.map(record => extractValuesFromRecord(record))
    outputds.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).json(outputLocation)

  }


  def extractValuesFromRecord(record: String): Metric = {
    val jsonRecord = new JSONObject(record)
    val timestamp = jsonRecord.getString("timestamp")
    val hostName = jsonRecord.getString("hostName")
    Metric(timestamp, hostName)
  }

}
```

Dependencies:

```
lazy val excludeJpountz = ExclusionRule(organization = "net.jpountz.lz4", name = "lz4")
lazy val excludeJpountz2 = ExclusionRule(organization = "org.lz4", name = "lz4-java")
lazy val excludeKafka = ExclusionRule(organization = "kafka-clients", name = "org.apache.kafka")


libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql-kafka-0-10" % "2.3.0" excludeAll(excludeJpountz, excludeKafka),
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.3.0" excludeAll(excludeJpountz, excludeJpountz2),
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.4.0" excludeAll(excludeJpountz, excludeJpountz2),
  "org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka" % "0.10.2.1" excludeAll (excludeJpountz),
  "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-api" % "2.8.2",
  "org.json" % "json" % "20190722"
)

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
  at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.initializeLogIfNecessary(Logging.scala:99)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$.initializeLogIfNecessary(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:369)
  at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.log(Logging.scala:46)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$.log(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:369)
  at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.logDebug(Logging.scala:58)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$.logDebug(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:369)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$ConfigUpdater.set(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:439)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$.kafkaParamsForDriver(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:394)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaRelation.buildScan(KafkaRelation.scala:64)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:308)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:63)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:63)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:439)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:93)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:78)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
  at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
  at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
  at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1336)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:67)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:93)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:78)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
  at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
  at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
  at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1336)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:67)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:93)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:78)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
  at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
  at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
  at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1336)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:67)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:93)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:78)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
  at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
  at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
  at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1336)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:67)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:93)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:78)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
  at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
  at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
  at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1336)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:67)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:93)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:78)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
  at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
  at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
  at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1336)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:67)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:93)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:72)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:68)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:77)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:77)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$toString$3.apply(QueryExecution.scala:208)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$toString$3.apply(QueryExecution.scala:208)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.stringOrError(QueryExecution.scala:100)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toString(QueryExecution.scala:208)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:74)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:654)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:273)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:267)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:225)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.json(DataFrameWriter.scala:526)
  ... 51 elided
```

It is very concise codeblock and there are no abstract functions any where. But it is confusing as I am getting the error. Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: can you share a stack trace?

Comment: @MichaelKreutz added stack trace

Comment: What Spark version?

Comment: Spark version is 2.3.0.2

Comment: @Bharat Can you share the dependencies as well?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous I am using kafka-clients-2.0.0.jar and I updated the post with dependencies

Comment: My assumption is that there are incompabilities in Kafka versions. According to the Spark + Kafka integration guide you should not add kafka-clients to your dependencies as it comes as transitive dependencies in spark-streaming-kafka010.

Comment: Why do you exclude kafka-clients? And for such a use case it should also not be necessary to add "kafka" as dependency, or am I overlooking something?

Comment: @mike This is also my guess.

Comment: @mike I tried to run without adding the kafka jar during runtime. But the execution is failing with saying cannot find ByteSerialization and Deserialization classes

Comment: According to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11/2.3.0 you could then add `libraryDependencies += "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % "0.10.0.1"` to your sbt dependencies.

Comment: Thank you @mike. I will try that and let you know